# I am unable to remove this loader from website

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am using this template: http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/archi-light/index-onepage.html I want to remove the preloader progress bar which shows progress of page loading in percentage. Files for this preloader are

Loader CSS File - www[dot]themenesia[dot]com/themeforest/archi-light/css/jpreloader.css

JS File - www[dot]themenesia[dot]com/themeforest/archi-light/js/jpreloader.js

Page CSS File - www[dot]themenesia[dot]com/themeforest/archi-light/css/style.css

I tried to delete both of these and removed css link and script from page. Also I removed this style from Page CSS File line 55:

```
body {
    display:none;
}
```

But still page is not loading and showing blank on screen. Please Help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
body {
    display: block !important;
}
```

add this to the bottom of your css.

**UPDATE**

Remove the following lines from `designesia.js`

```
// --------------------------------------------------
    // preloader
    // --------------------------------------------------

    //calling jPreLoader function with properties
    jQuery('body').jpreLoader({
        splashID: "#jSplash",
        splashFunction: function () {  //passing Splash Screen script to jPreLoader
            jQuery('#jSplash').children('section').not('.selected').hide();
            jQuery('#jSplash').hide().fadeIn(800);
            init_de();
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                splashRotator();
            }, 1500);
        }
    }, function () {    //jPreLoader callback function
        clearInterval();

        jQuery(function () {
            var v_url = document.URL;

            if (v_url.indexOf('#') != -1) {
                var v_hash = v_url.substring(v_url.indexOf("#") + 1);


                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery('#' + v_hash).offset().top - 70
                }, 200);
                return false;
            }
        });


    });

    // End of jPreLoader script
```

Comment: @Mistalis, yeah i know. A quick fix but  Let me fix it the correct way .

Comment: Thanks a lott @hunzaboy, it worked :)
I added 
    body {
           display: block !important;
     }

and removed the script from designesia.js

Comment: You don't' need to add body {display:block !important}, it should work without it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the loader has the following id: #jpreOverlay

try to add:

```
#jpreOverlay { display: none !important; }
```

to your css.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css this:

```
#jpreOverlay { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The screen is blank because you are hiding the body. The loader is most likely made with javascript, so to get rid of that javascript and the html for the loader. Also delete this line:

```
body {
   display: none;
}
```

Then the main page will then display and the loader will not.